# cumsum for each row according to different period on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

how to get "expected_column"?
the dataframe is sort_values by time,
how to calculate sum of last 'n' rows for each row group by 'ID' column, value of n  in 'rolling' columns.
One ID always have the same rolling, 2 IDs can have same rolling.

```
dct_data = {'ID': {0: 'a',
                   1: 'a',
                   2: 'a',
                   3: 'a',
                   4: 'a',
                   5: 'b',
                   6: 'b',
                   7: 'b',
                   8: 'b',
                   9: 'b'},
            'time': {0: '2022-12-23 14:56:00',
                     1: '2022-12-23 14:57:00',
                     2: '2022-12-23 14:58:00',
                     3: '2022-12-23 14:59:00',
                     4: '2022-12-23 15:00:00',
                     5: '2022-12-23 14:56:00',
                     6: '2022-12-23 14:57:00',
                     7: '2022-12-23 14:58:00',
                     8: '2022-12-23 14:59:00',
                     9: '2022-12-23 15:00:00'},
            'rolling': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2},
            'value': {0: 19, 1: 14, 2: 14, 3: 32, 4: 16, 5: 0, 6: 6, 7: 1, 8: 4, 9: 3} }

df_test = pd.DataFrame(dct_data)
expected_column = [0+0+19, 0+19+14,19+14+14,14+14+32,14+32+16,0+0,0+6,6+1,1+4,4+3]
df_test['expected_column'] = expected_column
```

```
[output]
ID  time                    rolling   value  expected_column
a   2022-12-23 14:56:00     3         19     19
a   2022-12-23 14:57:00     3         14     33
a   2022-12-23 14:58:00     3         14     47
a   2022-12-23 14:59:00     3         32     60
a   2022-12-23 15:00:00     3         16     62
b   2022-12-23 14:56:00     2         0      0
b   2022-12-23 14:57:00     2         6      6
b   2022-12-23 14:58:00     2         1      7
b   2022-12-23 14:59:00     2         4      5
b   2022-12-23 15:00:00     2         3      7
```

Comment: You say: "how to calculate sum of last 'n' rows for each row group by 'ID' column, value of n in 'rolling' columns", but in your example `expected_column` is simply using `n = 3` throughout. Shouldn't the correct answer for `ID == 2` with `rolling == 2` be: `0, 6, 7, 5, 7`?

Comment: you are right! i  just corrected it

Comment: Does a give ID in your data, always have the same rolling? so if id = 'a' it can have only 1 rolling value., but 2 ids can have same rolling 'a' and 'e' can have rolling value as 3. is this true?

Comment: Yes! One ID always have the same rolling, 2 IDs can have a same rolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. Do note, that this works for cases (like your example) where each ID has only one possible rolling window.

1. You need to first create a function that would apply over each "group" that is created by the ID variable. This would basically take the value columns, apply `.rolling` sum but take the corresponding value in `rolling` column
2. You then need to apply this to a `groupby` to fetch the column that you need.
3. Finally you need to set it as a new column in your original dataframe.

```
f = lambda x: x['value'].rolling(x['rolling'].unique()[0], min_periods=1).sum()
df_test['computed_columns'] = df_test.groupby('ID').apply(f).tolist()

print(df_test)
```

```
  ID                 time  rolling  value  expected_column  computed_columns
0  a  2022-12-23 14:56:00        3     19               19              19.0
1  a  2022-12-23 14:57:00        3     14               33              33.0
2  a  2022-12-23 14:58:00        3     14               47              47.0
3  a  2022-12-23 14:59:00        3     32               60              60.0
4  a  2022-12-23 15:00:00        3     16               62              62.0
5  b  2022-12-23 14:56:00        2      0                0               0.0
6  b  2022-12-23 14:57:00        2      6                6               6.0
7  b  2022-12-23 14:58:00        2      1                7               7.0
8  b  2022-12-23 14:59:00        2      4                5               5.0
9  b  2022-12-23 15:00:00        2      3                7               7.0
```